# Including a javascript file into a nested php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am working with the following three files:

```
index.php
menu.php
move.js
```

**menu.php**

```
//...........................
<button id="mover" type="button" >Extend</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/move.js"></script>
//........................
```

**move.js**

```
$("#move").click(function(){

    console.log("move");
    $("#container").animate({left: '5000px'}, "slow");
});
```

**index.php**

```
//............
<figure>
<?php include ("menu.php"); ?>
</figure>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/move.js"></script>
//.............
```

My issue is that every time I click the  "Extend" button (in menu.php), the event listener won't respond and it doesn't print to the console.

PS: I am new to php,and I am not sure if this is the right way to nest php files.

Comment: ```<button id="mover" type="button" >Extend</button>```. The id is `mover` not `move` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the name of the button `id` from `mover` to `move` and then your javascript will work.

**REPLACE**

```
<button id="mover" type="button" >Extend</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/move.js"></script>
```

**WITH**

```
 <button id="move" type="button" >Extend</button>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/move.js"></script>
```